# How can I write a code to define a range insdide a loop that will change its size?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use two Loops and the easy part is to count how many times does a "submodul" repeats in a defined and known range ("B3","B18"), this means the quantity of elements each submodul has. The difficult part comes when trying to count how many times does a "position" repeats for each different "submodul", this is because the amount of elements of each "submodul" is different so I have to adjust a range in a especial Loop to calculate how many times does a specific element (=Position) repeats within a "submodul".

The specific part that I need help with is the following:

```
positionrepetition = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").range("cells(3 + x + y - 1, 3)", "cells(3 + x + y - 1 + submodulrepetition,3"), position)
```

If I can manage to write it in a correct format I believe it will work. The problem is that normally I only use the range function when I know that the range is fixed or known, it doesn´t have to be calculated. I normally write for example: Range("A1","F10").Select

As you can see this is a fixed range, so I imagined that instead of using the format of Range("A1", "F10") I could  use the range function with the arguments ("Cells(1,1)","Cells(10,6)"). Please correct me if I´m wrong.

Here is the rest of the code for the Loop.

```
For x = 0 To numberofparts
    If Cells(3 + x, 18) = "1" Then
        submodul = Cells(3 + x, 2).Value
        submodulrepetition = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").range("B3", "B18"), submodul)
        For y = 1 To submodulrepetition
            position = Cells(3 + x + y - 1, 3).Value
            positionrepetition = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").range("cells(3 + x + y - 1, 3)", "cells(3 + x + y - 1 + submodulrepetition,3"), position)
        Next
    Else
    End If
    x = x + submodulrepetition - 1
 Next
```

To explain a little more, all data is gathered from Excel Sheets:

-All Information is gathered from a Excel sheet
-The "submodules" are in column B and they are arranged in numerical order. Every submodul repeats in this column as many elements it has.
-The "positions" (elements of the submodules) are in column C and can also repeat in the same column and even in other "Submodul"s.

All help will be appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Alejandro Farina

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line:

```
positionrepetition = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("cells(3 + x + y - 1, 3)", "cells(3 + x + y - 1 + submodulrepetition,3"), Position)
```

With :

```
positionrepetition = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(3 + x + y - 1, 3), Cells(3 + x + y - 1 + submodulrepetition, 3), Position))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Now I can use a range with different size each Loop.

Comment: @AlejandroF what happened here ? you took off the `V` ?

Comment: It was a mistake, I was trying out something

Answer (score 0):

**If the Range is going to Change by `Column/Row` use the following code to get the end of column or row:**

```
Dim GetColEnd, GetRowEnd As Integer

GetColEnd = Sheets("Sheet_Name").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
GetRowEnd = Sheets("Sheet_Name").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

**Use the `GetColEnd` `GetRowEnd` in your `Range` function for flexible `Column\Row` for example as follows:**

```
Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(GetRowEnd,GetColEnd)
```